# Calculating mean shift vector in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I'm looking for an elegant way to calculate the mean shift vector for a `uint8(960x540x3)` image in MATLAB. The meanshift vector is given by

[image: meanshift vector]

`S_h` is the neighborhood we are looking in given by a circle of radius `h`. In MATLAB I have built logical mask (`s_mask`) with those properties.

`w(x_i)` is the value of the probability map for a pixel with x-y coordinates. This is a scalar value. `w` is a 960x540 matrix.

`x` is the center of the neighborhood circle. I'm interested in finding a fast method in calculating such a vector with preferably no for loops but just matrix multiplications.

Comment: First you need to convert from `uint8` to `double`. Then I'd use `conv2` to convolve with the mask, which probably needs to be converted to `double` too. This gives you the numerator. `conv2` has several options as to what to do at the edges where the mask would be partly out of the image

Comment: convoling the mask with the map results in a awkwardly sized matrix (1079x1919).

Comment: That's because of the edge effects I mentioned in my previous comment. Try `conv2(...'same')` or `conv2(...'valid')` (explanation [here](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv2.html))